Can a regularizer be reverse engineered to induce precise modifications to the associated unregularized regression problem's solution?
The following is a picture of regularization in a regression problem...

The blue line is unregularized or less regularized, and the green line is more regularized.  Problems of this sort are often written as $\min_w\ (\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n l(h_w(x_i),\ y_i)}{n} + \lambda r(w))$, where the larger $\lambda$ is set, the closer the solution is to a straight, horizontal line.
This description sounds a lot like the dynamic behavior of a $1$-dimensional heat equation.  As depicted here and governed by the partial differential equation $T_t = \alpha T_{xx}$, the temperature distribution of a rod initialized with arbitrarily high volatility smooths out into a straight, horizontal line as time grows large.
While I expected something related to the heat equation to govern regularization, when I actually studied regularization, I did not find any connection.  Is there a way to intentionally construct a regularizer with a constant $\alpha$ equal to the thermal diffusivity constant from the heat equation, such that for each fixed value of $\alpha$, increasing $\lambda$ on the regularizer modifies the unregularized loss function solution identically to increasing $t$ in the $1$-dimensional heat equation with initial temperature distribution equal to the unregularized loss function solution (a "heat equation regularizer")?

you may be interested in "physics informed machine learning"

@JohnMadden yup, absolutely agree ;)
